# On admob, is it possible to get adblockers blocking the ad reward?

Tags: android, admob, ads, mobile-application

I am a beginner in this field of advertisements and I am trying to understand what are the best solutions to ensure advertising on the mobile application.
On our game project, we plan to use the rewarded video, and it must be fair play for all players, so no possibility of circumventing advertisements.

Do Ad-Networks, like Admob, have solutions against ad blockers (rooted and non rooted)?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.